# Iterators Incompatible Error

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error

I'm trying to write a function that takes two vectors and merges them together, alternating back and forth (i.e. v1 = 1,2,3 v2 = 4,5,6 would produce v3 = 1,4,2,5,3,6). Problem is, when I run my function I get an error saying that the 'vector iterator's are incompatible.' From my research I think that it has something to do with my use of the .begin() and .end() functions, but seeing as I've only been at this for a few months, I don;t know how to fix it. NOTE: The push_back on NULL is to leave an empty space in the vector.

Here's the code:

```
void merge(vector<double> x, vector<double> y, vector<double>& merged) {
    auto xStart = x.begin();
    auto yStart = y.begin();        

    while (xStart != x.end() && yStart != x.end()) {
        merged.push_back(*xStart);
        merged.push_back(*yStart);
       ++xStart;
       ++yStart;
   }
   if (xStart != x.end()) {
       while (xStart!= x.end()) {
           merged.push_back(*xStart);
           merged.push_back(NULL);
           ++xStart;
       }
   }
   if (yStart != y.end()) {
        while (yStart != y.end()) {
            merged.push_back(*yStart);
            merged.push_back(NULL);
            ++yStart;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: `yStart != x.end()` --> `yStart != y.end()`

Comment: If you run your code under a debugger you would find that the debugger indicated the line containing the error

Comment: `push_back(NULL)` is a mistake (may fail to compile on newer compilers), use `push_back(0.0)` instead.  And `if ( X ) while ( X )` is redundant, you could just go straight into the `while`.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo

```
while (xStart != x.end() && yStart != x.end()) {
                                      ^^^^^^
```

There must be

```
while (xStart != x.end() && yStart != y.end()) {
                                      ^^^^^^^
```

And this statement

```
merged.push_back(NULL);
```

does not make sense.

Also it is much better to declare the function like

```
void merge( const vector<double> &x, const vector<double> &y, vector<double>& merged );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void merge( const std::vector<T> &x, 
            const std::vector<T> &y, 
            std::vector<T> &merged ) 
{
    merged.reserve( merged.size() + x.size() + y.size() );

    auto xStart = x.begin();
    auto yStart = y.begin();        

    for ( ; xStart != x.end() && yStart != y.end(); ++xStart, ++yStart ) 
    {
        merged.push_back(*xStart);
        merged.push_back(*yStart);
    }


    for ( ; xStart != x.end(); ++xStart ) 
    {
        merged.push_back( *xStart );
    }

    for ( ; yStart != y.end(); ++yStart ) 
    {
        merged.push_back( *yStart );
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

    std::vector<int> merged;

    merge( v1, v2, merged );

    for ( int x : merged ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help! Just out of curiosity, why is sending them to the function as constants better?

Comment: @Sandweiche They are passed by constant references. This allows 1) to avoid of creating copies of the vectors and 2) to guarantee that the source vectors are not changed in the function.

Comment: I guess the original code was trying to zero-pad the shorter vector, e.g. `{1, 2, 3} + {4} = {1, 4, 2, 0, 3, 0}`